# How do I use a scrollbar and a button to select what line the user clicks on in a list in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I use a scrollbar and a button to select what line the user clicks on in a list in python?
I tried using the command of the button to the defined function Get... Do nae have a clue.
This is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *

def get():
    userline=leftside.get(line)
    print(userline) 

def scale():
    thescale=Tk()
    scroll=Scrollbar(thescale)
    scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    leftside = Listbox(thescale, yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
    for line in range(101):
        leftside.insert(END, "Scale "+str(line))

    leftside.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
    scroll.config(command=leftside.yview)

    selectbutton=Button(thescale, text="Select", command=get)
    selectbutton.pack()

    thescale.mainloop()

scale()
```

Comment: why do you put `def Get()` inside `def Scale()` ?

Comment: BTW: we use `lower_case` names for variables and functions - ie. `select_button`, `get()`. We use `CamelCase` names only for classes - ie. `Button`, `Scrollbar`,

Comment: i dont really know tbh... i just started this.

Comment: I did not know this, thank you.

Comment: BTW: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: put function `Get()` outside `Scale()` - and you can remove `Scale()` after `mainloop()`. Everything after `mainloop()` is executed after you close tkinter window.

Comment: I have made those changes. i have defined the whole code under Scale from: thescale=tk(), through to the thescale.mainloop() so thats why i have kept the scale()

Comment: Any other advice?

Comment: very importand advice: never change code in question (if it is not small typo) Now all comments have nothing do with your question. If you have new code then append in question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP changed all code in question.

Comment: all variables created in functions are `local` and they doesn't exist in other functions. You have to use global variable (created outside functions) and/or keyword `global` to have access in other functions.

Comment: i just made your changes? and i also copied it in wrong in the first place

Comment: I have made them global but when clicking the button it still only outputs the 100th line... i think i need to be able to identify each line individually somehow within the loop?

Comment: use `print(line)` inside `get()` and you see that it is always 100 - so `get(line)` always get 100th line.

Comment: `Listbox` has `.curselection()` to get indexes of selected lines - http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm

Answer (score 0):

The Listbox widget as an 'active' index that correspond to the item the user clicked on last. So `leftside.get('active')` will give you the item you want. In addition, if you move the `get` method out of `scale`, you need to make `leftside` a global variable, otherwise you cannot use it inside `get`.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Listbox, Button, Scrollbar

def get():
    userline=leftside.get('active')
    print(userline) 

def scale():
    global leftside
    thescale=Tk()
    scroll=Scrollbar(thescale)
    scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')

    leftside = Listbox(thescale, yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
    for line in range(101):
        leftside.insert('end', "Scale "+str(line))

    leftside.pack(side='left', fill='both')
    scroll.config(command=leftside.yview)

    selectbutton=Button(thescale, text="Select", command=get)
    selectbutton.pack()

    thescale.mainloop()

scale()
```